# Strange behavior of log4cl and iterate

Tags: loops, logging, common-lisp

I am starting to use `log4cl` and am facing a weird issue when using it inside an `iterate` loop. While `working` does show the name of the method it is empty for `not-working`.

Do I miss something obvious here? Or is there a bug in the combination of `iterate` and `log4cl`?

```
(ql:quickload "iterate")
(ql:quickload "log4cl")

(defpackage :minimal
  (:use #:cl #:iterate)) 

(in-package :minimal)

(defclass test ()
  ((a :documentation "test-a"
      :initform (make-array '(3 3)
                :element-type 'integer
                :initial-element 0)
      :initarg :a)))

(defvar *a* (make-instance 'test))

(defmethod not-working ((test test))
  (with-slots (a) test
    (iter
      (for i below 3)
      (iter
        (for j below 3)
        (unless (= 10 (aref a i j)) 
          (log:info "R: ~D C: ~D" i j))))))

(defmethod working ((test test))
  (with-slots (a) test
    (loop
      for i below 3
      do (loop
           for j below 3
           unless (= 10 (aref a i j))
             do (log:info "I: ~D J: ~D" i j)))))

(not-working *a*)
(working *a*)
```

**EDIT**

I see the issue only on `sbcl`. Using `ccl`the method name is displayed correctly. Furthermore, omitting the `(are...)` statement inside `unless` leads to a working version:

```
(defmethod also-working ((test test))
  (with-slots (a) test
    (iter
      (for i below 3)
      (iter
        (for j below 3)
        (unless (= 10 j) 
          (log:info "R: ~D C: ~D" i j))))))
```

Comment: So you are using SBCL? To me it looks like ITER does things which log4cl does not know how to deal with.

Comment: Yes, I am using SBCL, forgot to mention it. Thanks for confirming my observation.

Comment: I will add an issue at the `log4cl`github page.